# Navigating from a Contentpage to a TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Content page that is a Contains a list of items.
Then I have a TabbedPage that represents one of this items splitted (each tab represents a section of the item.. Categories, periods, etc)

Now, I want to click on the item of my list (contentPage) and navigate to the item (TabbedPage).

I tried with Navigation.PushAsync which works fine for me on IOS, however on Android I have an exception:
`System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

```
public partial class BudgetsPage : ContentPage
{
   //...
   async void OnItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
       var layout = (BindableObject)sender;
       var item = (BudgetItem)layout.BindingContext;
       var budgetManagement = new BudgetManagementPage(new BudgetDetailViewModel(item));
       await Navigation.PushAsync(budgetManagement);
   }
}
```

And the Tabbed page is something like

```
public partial class BudgetManagementPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public BudgetManagementPage(BudgetDetailViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            budgetManagementPage.Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new BudgetInfoTab(viewModel)) { IconImageSource = GetImageSource(IconFont.Information), Title="Info"});
            
        }

        private ImageSource GetImageSource(string iconName)
        {
            return new FontImageSource()
            {
                FontFamily = "materialWebFont",
                Glyph = iconName
            };
        }
    }
```

Somehow it looks like Android isn't expecting the tabbedpage on pushingAsync?

Does anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Try [tabview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview) instead of tabbed page. (Tabbed page is more like a container with multiple pages)

Comment: Add try catch and check which line is causing issue and get full exception details (stack trace). Will give you better understanding of issue. Then you can proceed on that basis.

Comment: a TabbedPage should be the root view, and is not intended to work when contained within a NavigationPage.  If you really want to go this route, instead of using NavigationPage, you can just change your App.MainPage to toggle between your LIstView page and TabbedPage.  Or consider using TabView as @Shaw suggests

Comment: Yeah, it worked with Tabview. Thanks all.